# Stop / kill WebRTC media stream

Tags: stream, webrtc, media, getusermedia

How to completely kill the WebRTC media stream?

**`MediaStream.stop()` is not working anymore.**

*Testing in Chrome 47, Mac OS 10.11.*

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Use `stream.getTracks().forEach(track => track.stop());`.

`stream.stop()` was deprecated.

Comment: Is it possible to launch tracks again once they are stopped?

Comment: No, stopped tracks are [ended](http://w3c.github.io/mediacapture-main/getusermedia.html#widl-MediaStreamTrack-stop-void).

Answer (score 0):

For all browsers

```
if (microphone_data.media_stream) {
    microphone_data.media_stream.getTracks().forEach(function (track) { track.stop(); });
}
```

Comment: What is `microphone_data` and what is `media_stream`? Those are not defined in the HTML5 media API.

Comment: @Dai: Those are his variables. `media_stream` would be an instance of the HTML5 [`MediaStream`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaStream)