# Invoking getLocalStreams on closed/closing peer connection

Tags: firefox, webrtc

I'm trying to invoke `getLocalStreams` on a "closing" peer connection. (I'm not sure if the peer connection is actually closed at this point).

```
peerConnection.onsignalingstatechange = function (e) {
    if (e.target.iceConnectionState === 'closed') {
      var streams = e.target.getLocalStreams();
      ...
    }
}
```

However, [this seems to cause Firefox to crash](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1259728).

I'm trying to access the local streams through the peer connection, so I don't have to keep track of them myself. (This doesn't seem far fetched, since the peer connections offers `getLocalStreams`).

I'm wondering if there is another way to close any open streams, without keeping track of the streams myself?

Before using the `peerConnection.onsignalingstatechange` event handler I tried accessing the streams (`getLocalStreams`) when the connection is actually closed and I get an `InvalidStateError: Peer connection is closed`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Stop / kill WebRTC media stream](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34966809/stop-kill-webrtc-media-stream)

Comment: Local cameras are `MediaStream`s gotten from `getUserMedia`. Has nothing to do with peer connection.

Comment: Thx @jib. My original question was misleading. It is not about stopping the streams and more about accessing properties from the peer connection.