# stop WebRTC media stream

Tags: webrtc

I have started using `navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({audio: true, video:false})` a media stream and it is working fine. Now i want it to stop on a button click but i couldn't find any workable solutions.
As per my research WebRTC has depreciated `stream.stop()` but i also found some alternatives like in [Stop/Close webcam which is opened by navigator.getUserMedia](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11642926/stop-close-webcam-which-is-opened-by-navigator-getusermedia)
 but solutions here are not working either.

Is there any workable solution?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Stop / kill WebRTC media stream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34966809/stop-kill-webrtc-media-stream)

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaStreamTrack/stop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instanciate stream :

```
    navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ audio: true, video: false})
    .then(stream => {
        // attach this stream to window object so you can reuse it later
        window.localStream = stream;
        // Your code to use the stream
    })
    .catch((err) =>{
        console.log(err);
    });
```

Remove stream :

```
localStream.getTracks().forEach((track) => {
    track.stop();
});
```